# can the gpu access memory allocated by malloc?

Tags: cuda, malloc, nvidia, gpgpu, unified-memory

I am trying to check if the GPU can access the memory allocated by the system allocator (e.g malloc).

I am using Cuda 10.2 and the documentation mentions that the device should support pageableMemoryAccessUsesHostPageTables. but when I checked it on my machine, it returns 0.

I want to know if this feature is supported on x86?

[nvidai-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUaZZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not available on x86.  It [is available on Power9](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-system-allocator).  You may wish to investigate managed memory (perhaps with oversubscription), or pinned host allocation using `cudaHostAlloc`